# Can django use an external database?

Tags: django

Can django use an external database? I mean, if you have one server for the db and other n-servers with the web server, can django use the db on an external machine? Can django do queries via internet to another django db?

Comment: Yes, it can, but will you open a public network port to your database?

Comment: No I won't.  It wil be in the local lan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your database and web server can be on separate servers.  You just have to specify in your settings file the host.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

Answer (score 1):

As [the relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/) states, Django is capable of using multiple databases. Whether remote access is supported will depend on which one you choose to use  - but, as a general rule, it is supported, with the notable exception of `sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access the database from anywhere. But they(you) need to provide database privileges for your IP. some code is like,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': Remote Host,
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

You can also use external django package https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url for deployment.

Comment: It looks like the code snippet you posted comes from "settings.py". Since this is a py file, is the best way to include credentials to import os and then reference environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I reach this post, but in my case, I need to access another database. My intention is create an application that report informationa from another database. I needed to use two databases. I found the way in the django documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Do you want to use Django's ORM with the other database, or simply query it directly with sql (which database type is it)? If the latter, connect to it via normal means and retrieve what you need. Nothing in Django stops you from connecting to other datasources (ex: https://swcarpentry.github.io/sql-novice-survey/10-prog/index.html) but if you want to use the ORM then the documentation should provide enough to get started.